# Linear transformation finding matrix of $T_c$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $c$ in $R$, define $T_c : R^n \to R$ by $T_c (x) = cx$ for all $x$ in $R^n$. Show that $T_c$ is a linear transformation and find its matrix.

I don't understand the question. For $T_c$  is $c$ the matrix and we are supposed to find $c$? Would the matrix just be $$
    \begin{matrix}
    c & 0 & 0  ...0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question must have a typo somewhere, because $cx$ would be an element of $R^n$ with your settings. Also, try to indicate what you have tried, or what is unclear to you in the definitions of the words that you use (linear transformation, for instance).

Comment: Yes there was an typo. I don't know where to start with this question the way it's defined is unclear to me what does the subscript $c$ represent?

Comment: Observe that, as fdefined, it is $\;T_c:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no "its matrix". There are infin ite matrices corresponding to different basis of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ for $\;T\;$.

You have to apply $\;T\;$ on some basis of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ and write down the result as a linear combination of the same basis (this is the easiest, most useful, case). Say, for example with the standard matrix $\;e\;$:

$$T_c(1,0,...,0):=(c,0,...,0)=c\cdot(1,0,...,0)+0\cdot(0,1,0,...,0)+\ldots+0\cdot(0,0,...,1)$$

and do the same for every element of the standard matrix. Now take the transpose of the coefficients matrix, and that is your matrix for this choice of basis :

$$[T_c]_e=\begin{pmatrix}c&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&c&0&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&0&c\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: How can I show that it is linear transformation?

Comment: @localita With the definition. It is practically trivial to show that.